# Multiple Cores running in rostest

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, rostest, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running tests in the latest navigation branch, but keep getting errors when I run

```
catkin_make run_tests
```

The errors claim that there is already a roscore instance open on that port. Full output of the command is seen [here](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/stuff/output.log) but the relevant bit is...

```
-- run_tests.py: execute commands
  /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostest --pkgdir=/home/dlu/catkin/src/navigation/costmap_2d --package=costmap_2d --results-filename test_simple_driving_test.xml /home/dlu/catkin/src/navigation/costmap_2d/test/simple_driving_test.xml
... logging to /home/dlu/.ros/log/rostest-serenity-8918.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/dlu/catkin/build/test_results/costmap_2d/rostest-test_simple_driving_test.xml
[ WARN] [1368241605.099039962]: Message from [/rosbag] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [base_laser]. Resolved locally to [/base_laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1368241605.108304546, 19.527194170]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 19.527194 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /base_scan topic.
testsimple_driving_test ... ERROR!
ERROR: roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://serenity:22422/
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 332, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostest/runner.py", line 121, in fn
    succeeded, failed = self.test_parent.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostest/rostest_parent.py", line 81, in launch
    return self.runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 644, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 620, in _setup
    self._launch_master()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 381, in _launch_master
    raise RLException("roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. \nPlease kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.\nThe ROS_MASTER_URI is %s"%(m.uri))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However running the tests with the individual command works just fine.

/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostest --pkgdir=/home/dlu/catkin/src/navigation/costmap_2d --package=costmap_2d --results-filename test_simple_driving_test.xml /home/dlu/catkin/src/navigation/costmap_2d/test/simple_driving_test.xml

The CMake command for the above listed test is...

```
add_rostest(test/simple_driving_test.xml)
catkin_add_gtest(module_tests test/module_tests.cpp)
```

In the words of "David after Dentist," "WHY IS THIS HAPPENING? IS THIS GOING TO BE FOREVER?"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62553/multiple-cores-running-in-rostest/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-10**:
What do the unit test commands in your CMakeLists.txt look like? (Please edit your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The actual problem is literally too many cores. I have a dual core laptop and the catkin_make has this option:

```
-j [JOBS], --jobs [JOBS]
                    Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run
                    simultaneously. Defaults to the environment variable
                    ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS and falls back to the number of CPU
                    cores.
```

Since I have two cores, it was running two tests at the same time with the same port number.

I have posted [a ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/224).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be the same as a problem I had. Check my earlier question: [how does rostest work with catkin?](http://answers.ros.org/question/54075/how-does-rostest-work-with-catkin/)

Unless your gtest is a standalone non-ROS test, try commenting it out in your CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostest uses a fixed rosmaster and can therefore not be invoked in parallel. So catkin_make should not automatically append -j flags when running tests. This has already been fixed in catkin_make (https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/c199d7b2f356b55ba4bf83ea45900482f8bd7a96) which will be available with the next patch release.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1